# Can I use Boost's format library to replace iostream?

Tags: c++, boost, iostream, stdio

I don't like to use `<iostream>` in C++ Library. I prefer to use something that is similar to "printf" and "scanf" in `<stdio.h>`.

Can I use Boost's format library to replace `<iostream>` in all my C++ program ?

Comment: Try https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt.git

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boost Format only does the formatting bit. You still need iostream to actually make something appear on the screen.

Of course, using them together will achieve the parity with `printf` you are looking for. And it does so without sacrificing type-safety (though that's not a huge issue these days, since the compiler will usually warn about bad printf arguments).

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know about this. Can I say that if I use <iostream> + Boost Format Library, then I can get the features I want (similar to <stdio.h> but type-safe)? Thanks.

Comment: @CMW Yes, this is exactly the goal of Boost.Format.

Comment: @Vicente: Thank you. But unfortunately Boost.Format doesn't work with istream.

Answer (score 5):

Boost.Format works with ostreams. You use it as follows

```
cout << boost::format("%2% %1%") % 36 % 77;
```

or like

```
string s2 = str( format("%2% %1%") % 36 % 77 );
```

and the print the string as you want.

Boost.Format doesn't works with istreams.

Answer (score 2):

You can continue to use `printf` in C++, nothing wrong with that. Just `#include <cstdio>` and you're good to go. Of course, `iostream` has several benefits (type-safety being the big one) - so I'd still recommend switching.

Comment: From what I've heard, <cstdio> is same like <stdio.h>, it is not type-safe. I want something that is as good as <iostream>, which is type-safe, but offer something similar to "printf" and "scanf". Thanks.

Comment: `nothing wrong with that`: Isn't lack of type safety something wrong with printf? :P

Comment: I don't think type-safety is that bit a deal here. As long as the first argument to `printf` is a literal, most compilers will warn about potential type violations.

Comment: @Marcelo: Thank you. Can I say that I can continue to use <cstdio>/<stdio.h> in all my C++ program without any problem ?

Comment: @CMW: Yes, but there are minor hazards. stdio and iostream may not synchronise buffers between each other, so you could find that things print out of order.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos: Unless you use `sync_with_stdio`.

Answer (score 0):

printf and scanf are limited in the way you cannot use your own objects with them.

If you're using C++, you'll need to know a bit about streams, because that's the standard of the language. In C++ you can create stream operators for your own objects and have them work perfectly with streams.

Of course, you can use boost::format, but it will only be for formatted output. I like boost::format, and it's very useful, when you're using localisation for instance (translatable strings).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer, as given by others, is yes, but there is no equivalent for `scanf` in Boost-format.  However, an alternative is to use [Boost's Spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html) library which has both input and output capabilities via the Karma and Qi components, respectively.  This may very well be overkill for what you are doing, though, as it is a full parser/generator implementation.